# How do I load ecb at emacs start up?

Tags: emacs

I am having trouble loading ecb at emacs startup.

```
d@d:$ apt-file search ecb.el
ecb: /etc/emacs/site-start.d/55ecb.el
ecb: /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/ecb/ecb.el
emacspeak: /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/emacspeak/lisp/emacspeak-ecb.el
xemacs21-basesupport: /usr/share/xemacs21/xemacs-packages/lisp/ecb/ecb.elc
xemacs21-basesupport-el: /usr/share/xemacs21/xemacs-packages/lisp/ecb/ecb.el.gz
```

my .emacs file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/ecb/")
(require 'ecb)
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not getting any errors, you probably just need:

```
(ecb-activate)
```

after those lines.

Answer (score 1):

What you've done is not necessary: the Ubuntu package contains everything that's needed to make the list packages available to Emacs instances. All you need to do is enable the features you want. This has to be done on a per-user basis so as not to annoy the users who don't want those features. In the case of `ecb`, if you want it active all the time, call `(ecb-activate)` in your `.emacs`. If you want a more complex set up, read the “Installation and first steps” chapter in the ecb manual, but skip the “Installation” section which the distribution has already done for you.